# Синтаксис объявления функции

Tags: javascript

Чем отличается запись

```
var a = function() { }
```

от

```
function a() { }
```

?

Answer (score 2):

`function a() { }` - создается до выполнения кода и вызывать ее можно до объявления

`var a = function() { }` - создастся по ходу выполнения кода и вызывать ее можно только после объявления